# Regular Expression is not working for SSN

Tags: javascript

SSN i have added a bootstrap validation but is not working

```
SSN: {
     validators: {
        notEmpty: {
                  message: 'Social Security number is required and cannot be empty'
                },
         regexp: {
                     // regexp: /^\d{9}$/,
                        regexp: /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/,
                       message: 'Social Security Number must be 9 digits'
                                }


                            }
                        },
```

Comment: What isn't working? What is the format you want to match, what did you try, what did you expect and what did you get? The question is tagged `C#` and yet you posted a snippet that has nothing to do with C#

Comment: I want Social Security Number should display in XXXXXXXXX (i.e., 123-45-6789)

Comment: Please get into a habit of NEVER saying _It is not working_.  Elaborate on what that means. What are you observing and what are you expecting to observe?

Comment: Write that in the question itself. Post *actual* code and explain what's wrong. As it is, it's impossible to answer why you have any kind of problem with C# when you post some unrelated strings

Answer (score -1):

Try this pattern: `^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$`

`\d` is a digit, `{X}` is repeat the previous element `X` times.

Adding ^ at the beginning and $ at the end will cause the regex to only match if the entire string is a SSN. Without those anchors strings like abc123-45-6789xyz would also match.

Comment: Well it's tested as working for me.  Not sure why a downvote for that.  Maybe it's something else in your implementation.  Explain your issue in more detail.